# Hide/Show Content at Specific Scroll Positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve an effect similar to what is happening in the blue circles on http://fresh01.co.za/. When scrolled into the focus of a particular post, the content within the blue circles changes to reflect the post in focus.

Just to clarify, I am curious about the jQuery specifically. I am already aware how to create the css part of the effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to try the jQuery WayPoints plugin:

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

This plugin allows you to attach events to specific scroll points (elements) on a page.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely looks like it'll help me out.